# When I run the code it says "TypeError: unlink() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_ok'"

Tags: python, filesystems

This is my code. It is everything I have in my programme:

```
from pathlib import Path
new_dir = Path.home() / "new_directory"
file_path = new_dir / "program2.py"
file_path.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

The file program2.py does not exist; that is why I wanted to set the missing_ok parameter to True so that it would not raise a FileExistsError. But every time I run the code it gives me the following message:

file_path.unlink(missing_ok=True)
TypeError: unlink() got an unexpected keyword argument 'missing_ok'

Do I have an outdated version of python or have I made a mistake in the code, help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `missing_ok` parameter was added to `Path.unlink` only on python `3.8`. You should upgrade python to newer version if you want to use this parameter.

You can check your python version with the command `python -V`

Comment: Yeh, I just tried to run the code on another IDE I use and it worked. thx

Answer (score 3):

As answered by napuzba, `missing_ok` is only available on python 3.8 or above.

If you still have to use python 3.7 or below, you can do this:

```py
if file_path.exists():
    file_path.unlink()
```

If you want to catch the exception:

```py
try:
    file_path.unlink()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass # maybe do something here
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I used `os.unlink()` instead of `pathlib.Path.unlink()`